# Pagination restores deleted rows by jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have a table that displays some data, each row has a delete button which calls an ajax method that deletes the row from the database. Then it calls a jquery method that deletes the row from the client side and it works. But, when moving to another page using the bootstrap table pagination and returned back to the page I deleted records from, the deleted rows appear again.

What could the problem be?

Jquery:

```
$('#authorsDataTableBody').on("click",".deleteAuthor", function (params) {
    var authorID =  $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");  
    var dataToPost ='id=' + authorID +'&type=' + authorType;
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    $.getJSON("/Home/DeleteAuthor", dataToPost);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure ,if it was deleted from the database ? and from the view ??

Comment: Yes sure. It was deleted and  it does not appear again after refreshing the page as well as html tree. it seems like the pagination keeps its version of data and it does not affected by any other jquery code!

Comment: This is interesting, Can you try activating/initializing the pagination again when data is deleted from ajax post (i know it makes no sense, but can you try?). Also is there any specific pagination library you are using? can you tell that?

Comment: check  rhytonix's answer below in the comments. "The problem happens because the browser caches the initial version of the page ....etc"

Answer (score 1):

You're removing the deleted rows on clicking the button without checking the server response. So if the server failed to delete the rows, the client-side won't be aware and would still removes the `tr`.

Also, `$.getJSON` performs a `GET` request which isn't what you want (you want a `POST` request), so you should use [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead, and move the client-side removal code into the `.done()` callback method of `$.post` or the `.success()` method of `$.ajax`.

Comment: yes I already have used $.post instead. But, I have no problem with the server side. the data is successfully deleted from the database and from the html tree using js code. and after refreshing the page, all is Ok. the problem appears when I try to move between pages, the data pops up again!.  it seems like the pagination code keeps its version of data and it does not affected by any other jquery code! and it's solved when I refresh the page (as the real data comes directly from the database)

Comment: The problem happens because the browser caches the initial version of the page (before any deletion), and when you click the back button (after deletion and navigating to another page), the browser reads the cached version instead of calling the server, so it ignores the DOM modifications performed by jquery. What you can do is either disable the page caching from the server by utilizing the OutputCache attribute, or perform page reload using JavaScript using location.reload() when the user clicks the back-button.